# How to untwist a twisted STL model from microCT scanning

Tags: mesh, transforms

I've got some STL models created from microCT scans that have an undesirable twist in them. I was wondering how I could use Blender to remove the twists using something like proportional editing. The STL models are very large (>150MB) and contain upwards of 6 million triangles.

I can import them into Blender but when I try proportional editing the mesh gets all distorted. Would it possible to create a mesh plane of similar x-y dimensions, sub-divide it, and somehow link it to the STL model so that the proportional changes in the mesh are reflected in the STL?

End view of twisted STL
[image]

Closeup view of triangles
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Turns out the **Simple Deform** modifier works perfectly for this type of thing!

Steps for Blender 2.81:

1. Import the STL file into Blender using **File, Import, Stl**
2. If required, rotate the model so that the twist axis is aligned with the X, Y or Z axis
3. In **Object mode**, select the entire STL object
4. Go to the **Modifier** tab and select the **Simple Deform** modifier. By default the Twist operation will be selected.
5. Select the axis along which the twist in the model is aligned.
6. Adjust the **Deform Angle** until the twist is removed or at least as small as you can get it.
7. To save the corrected STL, go to **File, Export, Stl**, give it a different filename and click Export STL.

Comment: Is this answer sufficient?